# Plotting disproportionate sets of data

Tags: pgfplots

I solved an optimisation problem for three cases. I intend to plot the results as a groupplot (essentially a 3 by 1 groupplot). Since I present six sets of data in each plot, I get a graph that looks like this:[image]

Due to the disproportionality of the datasets, we observe a near parallel line for 3 datasets, while the other lines show that the system design costs increase wrt routing costs. What I'd like to have is for the near parallel line to also show that the system design costs increase. However, this information gets suppressed. Could you please suggest some alternatives for this anomaly? Please find the code here

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every mark/.append style={mark size=.7pt}]
    \begin{axis}[
                scale=0.81,
                legend style={
                at = {(.48,-.8)},anchor=south},%at={(0.5,-0.34)},anchor=north},
                %legend columns = -1,
                xmin=0,xmax=50,
                ymin=0,ymax=400000,
                ymode = log,
                xlabel={routing costs},
                ylabel={system design costs},
                legend style={font=\small}]

\addplot
    coordinates {
        (0, 310006.712271894)
        (10, 312781.712271894)
        (20, 315556.712271894)
        (30, 318331.712271894)
        (40, 321106.712271894)
        (50, 323881.712271894)
    };\addlegendentry{Centralised RAN}
    
\addplot+
    coordinates {
        (0, 237.689033351856)
        (10, 535.932112624024)
        (20, 834.175191896192)
        (30, 1132.41827116836)
        (40, 1430.66135044053)
        (50, 1728.90442971269)
    };\addlegendentry{Distributed RAN}
    
\addplot+
    coordinates {
        (0, 47.5517657268742)
        (10, 404.104349185922)
        (20, 709.528125267976)
        (30, 1014.06344997298)
        (40, 1317.76112473382)
        (50, 1620.73092429476)     }
    ;\addlegendentry{Fluid RAN}
      \addplot+          coordinates {
        (0, 310007.104063121)
        (10, 312782.104063121)
        (20, 315557.104063121)
        (30, 318332.104063121)
        (40, 321107.104063121)
        (50, 323882.104063121)
    };\addlegendentry{Centralised RAN - HIGH}
    
\addplot+
    coordinates {
        (0, 93699.4500521545)
        (10, 94466.4160045098)
        (20, 95233.3819568651)
        (30, 96000.3479092204)
        (40, 96767.3138615757)
        (50, 97534.279813931)
    };\addlegendentry{Distributed RAN - HIGH}
    
\addplot+
    coordinates {
        (0, 90079.5312740768)
        (10, 90995.7138828325)
        (20, 91787.0309120226)
        (30, 92568.9759214698)
        (40, 93347.4344093317)
        (50, 94123.854677605)
    };\addlegendentry{Fluid RAN - HIGH}
    
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The problem is in the data itself.  You can either show the bottom two lines well using log scale, or the top three lines well using a linear scale, but not all 5 at the same time.

Comment: Indeed, I've been trying some tricks like split-pane using groupplots, axis-break but they don't seem so convincing.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I created a part linear/part semilog plot.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every mark/.append style={mark size=.7pt}]
    \begin{axis}[name=lower,
                scale=0.81,
                height=3cm, width=6cm, scale only axis,
                xmin=0,xmax=50,
                ymin=0,ymax=50000,
                ymode = log,
                xlabel={routing costs},
                ylabel={\hspace*{2.5cm}system design costs},
                ylabel shift=2cm,
                legend to name=part1,
                legend style={font=\small}]
\addplot+
    coordinates {
        (0, 47.5517657268742)
        (10, 404.104349185922)
        (20, 709.528125267976)
        (30, 1014.06344997298)
        (40, 1317.76112473382)
        (50, 1620.73092429476)     }
    ;\addlegendentry{Fluid RAN}
\addplot+
    coordinates {
        (0, 237.689033351856)
        (10, 535.932112624024)
        (20, 834.175191896192)
        (30, 1132.41827116836)
        (40, 1430.66135044053)
        (50, 1728.90442971269)
    };\addlegendentry{Distributed RAN}
\end{axis}
    
\begin{axis}[shift=(lower.north west),
        scale=0.81,
        height=3cm, width=6cm, scale only axis,
        xticklabels={}, cycle list shift=2,
        xmin=0,xmax=50,
        ymin=50000,ymax=400000,
        legend to name=part2,
        legend style={font=\small}]

\addplot
    coordinates {
        (0, 310006.712271894)
        (10, 312781.712271894)
        (20, 315556.712271894)
        (30, 318331.712271894)
        (40, 321106.712271894)
        (50, 323881.712271894)
    };\addlegendentry{Centralised RAN}    
    

      \addplot+          coordinates {
        (0, 310007.104063121)
        (10, 312782.104063121)
        (20, 315557.104063121)
        (30, 318332.104063121)
        (40, 321107.104063121)
        (50, 323882.104063121)
    };\addlegendentry{Centralised RAN - HIGH}
    
\addplot+
    coordinates {
        (0, 93699.4500521545)
        (10, 94466.4160045098)
        (20, 95233.3819568651)
        (30, 96000.3479092204)
        (40, 96767.3138615757)
        (50, 97534.279813931)
    };\addlegendentry{Distributed RAN - HIGH}
    
\addplot+
    coordinates {
        (0, 90079.5312740768)
        (10, 90995.7138828325)
        (20, 91787.0309120226)
        (30, 92568.9759214698)
        (40, 93347.4344093317)
        (50, 94123.854677605)
    };\addlegendentry{Fluid RAN - HIGH}
    
 \end{axis}

\node[below=1cm,align=center] at (lower.south) {\pgfplotslegendfromname{part1}\\
  \pgfplotslegendfromname{part2}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @John but as you've mentioned, the data has to be re-interpreted in some other way.